# jQuery UI position give only horizontal position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My object `at` and `of` it's horizontal value is what I want, but I don't want it's vertical value. Is there a way for me to give it only the horizontal value of my `of` object?

```
dialog.dialog({
  position: {
    my: 'center',
    at: 'center none',
    of: jQuery("#aktiivsedValjakutsedList")
  }
});
```

Solution

Instead of basing to position on the table i made it like so

```
my: 'center',
at: 'center+'offset,
of: window
```

And i calculate the offset by gettind the difference of the tables horizontal center and windows horizontal center.

Comment: so you want it to sit where on the page? Currently it looks like you have it centered at the top of the page

Comment: I want it to be horizontali at the center of aktiivsedValjakutsedList nut vertically i want it to be at the center of the window. Currently problem is that that height of the object changes, so the vertical center point of it changes. but width and the objects location is always the same, so the horizontal center is what i want to get.

Comment: @MarkoTaht it's really not clear what is not working for you. There may be other CSS or jQuery code that is being applied to your dialog. Remember that the values for `position` are based on the `top` and `left` values of the document or element. It sounds like you'd like the `top` value to be variable and the `left` value to be consistent. Please confirm.

Comment: Imagine a page with 2 tables side by side. On the right table when you click a dialog opens. Currently dialog center = table center. This is bad, because if the table has 1 or 2 entries the center is too high up and dialog is partially covered up by page header. What i want to do is have the dialog have the tables horizontal center but, vertical center should be the windows vertical center.

Comment: @Twisty its more like i want the top top be consistent and left be variable.

Comment: @MarkoTaht Would need to see the HTML Table or more about what you are trying to do. Please create a jsfiddle.net or other such working example.